# Time-based workflow email notification alerts to customers

Tags: trigger, workflow

So I've been reading up on Workflows, Triggers and Email Alerts and what I want to do appears possible without having to write custom Apex stuff.

Our objective is to send email reminders to customers when their yearly maintenance contrats are about to expire.

So I have created a custom field in the Standard object *Accounts*,  called *Maintenance Start Date__c*. And created a Workflow rule (Create>Workflow & Approvals>Workflow Rules) for Account with a Rule Criteria formula that should evaluate to true as the DATE field is NOT null.

ex. `NOT( ISNULL( Maintenance__c ) )`.

My logic is that a Time-Dependent Workflow Action of say **345 Days After Account: Maintenance start date** will trigger an email alert. For the email addresses I'm starting with just a test email to myself as a User.

```
Evaluation Criteria :  created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria
```

But the alert is not working when I enter a date in the *Maintenance Start Date__c* field which is backdated to over 345 days. Both workflow and alert are "Active". Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: your example WF criteria rule -- shouldn't it be `NOT(ISBLANK(Maintenance_start_Date__c))` ? If yes, pls edit your post.  BTW, the general approach to these issues is to look at Setup | Monitor | Time-based workflows as well as turn on debug log for yourself, repeat the test, and then examine the Workflow section of the log

Comment: Thanks for the info about Monitor and Debug as I wasn't aware of these functions in SF.  About the expression, SF says  ISBLANK has the same functionality as ISNULL, but also supports text fields. Either way my Alert is not getting sent :(     The field name/label is Maintenance start date but the API Name is Maintenance__c (which is what gets inserted with "Insert Field" button)

Comment: From the Log it would appear I have no WF action :

Comment: 14:49:20.354 (354739398)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:Account
14:49:20.373 (373889249)|WF_RULE_EVAL_BEGIN|Workflow
14:49:20.373 (373924716)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Account: Adi 001e000000RjLao]|Account Alert Maintenance|01Qe000000055fV|ON_CREATE_OR_TRIGGERING_UPDATE
14:49:20.374 (374097045)|WF_RULE_NOT_EVALUATED
14:49:20.374 (374156104)|WF_SPOOL_ACTION_BEGIN|Workflow
14:49:20.374 (374164550)|WF_ACTION| None
14:49:20.374 (374167944)|WF_RULE_EVAL_END

Comment: 14:49:20.374 (374176698)|WF_TIME_TRIGGERS_BEGIN
14:49:20.377 (377129476)|WF_TIME_TRIGGER|[Account: Adi 001e000000RjLao]|345 after 00Ni000000FPup0|Account Alert Maintenance 01Qe000000055fV|08:00:00.000
14:49:20.386 (386051342)|WF_ACTIONS_END| None
14:49:20.386 (386059330)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:Account

Comment: Changed Rule Criteria from "formula" to "criteria" and created a new Account and now I have a log showing WF_ACTION| Email Alert: 1; But this only happens on creation and not on updating(changing the date of maintenance) according to Evaluation Criteria : created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria

Answer (score 0):

**Preamble (altered to reflect comment trail)**

With a rule `NOT( ISNULL( Maintenance__c ) )` and workflow evaluation criteria of:

```
Evaluation Criteria :  created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria
```

The workflow rule only executes if the value of the field changes from null to nonNull or when the record is created.

The workflow will not evaluate at all if the `Maintenance__c` changes from one non-null value to another non-null value as that won't "subsequently meet criteria" (true is still true). Note, for time-based workflows,  the `Every time it is edited` evaluation radio button is not available.

Once the time-based workflow is entered for the object, the object stays in that workflow until the time-based condition is no longer true (maintenance start date becomes null) or the time trigger finally happens (345 days after `account.maintenance_start_date__c`). If the maintenance start date is changed on the Account, the time based trigger adjusts accordingly per the doc:

> What happens if I update the value of a date field used in a time
>   trigger? If you update the date field used in a time trigger,
>   Salesforce recalculates the time trigger as long as the time trigger
>   has not yet fired and the recalculation does not reschedule the time
>   trigger to a date in the past.
>
> For example, if a workflow rule alerts the opportunity owner seven
>   days before the opportunity close date and the close date is set to
>   2/20/2008, Salesforce sends the alert on 2/13/2008. If you update the
>   close date to 2/10/2008 and the current date is 2/2/2008 or before,
>   Salesforce reschedules the alert for 2/3/2008. The evaluation date of
>   pending actions is ALWAYS reevaluated and updated if necessary
>   irrespective of the rule criteria. Of course, if the rule is evaluated
>   to false, it does not matter as the actions are removed from the
>   queue.

If you were backdating to a date in the past, per the doc, the time trigger does not adjust

Comment: Thanks for this insight. Unfortunately SF says with that option "Created, and Every time it's edited" that "You cannot add time-dependent workflow actions with this option." Any other workarounds possible ?

Comment: ah right, one more thing I should have checked; edited post

Comment: Thanks. I can create an Account and enter a maintenance start date ex. 1-2-2012 which is well beyond the 345 days set by the time trigger and it works --> 345 Days After Account: Maintenance start date. However I needed a workaround for the issue of Evaluation Criteria "Every time it is edited" to remain true if I want to edit the date. My workaround is a bit messy but I can clear the date, save the changes and re-enter a new date and it works like a gem because the value of the field is changing from null to nonNull :)